# Does kafka log retention applies to __consumer_offsets topic(default topic)?

Tags: apache-kafka

We want to change log retention of our kafka topics from default to some 30 days. So we used below command to do that.

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181--entity-type topics --entity-name testTopic --alter --add-config retention.ms=2592000000
```

But what happens to `__consumer_offsets` topic. Does this topic also requires retention to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

The `__consumer_offsets` topic retention time is controlled by the `offsets.retention.minutes` parameter, which is part of the [broker configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) params.

> After a consumer group loses all its consumers (i.e. becomes empty)
>   its offsets will be kept for this retention period before getting
>   discarded. For standalone consumers (using manual assignment), offsets
>   will be expired after the time of last commit plus this retention
>   period.

Its default value was 1440 minutes (1 day) until [KIP-186](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-186%3A+Increase+offsets+retention+default+to+7+days), which marked the retention time to 10800 minutes (7 days) as default.

Comment: That means, if I update offsets.retention.minutes property from default value i.e 7 days to some 30 days in my server.properties file, then it will be effected automatically or we need to restart my kafka?. And how can we check whether the updated value is effected or not?

Comment: since it's a broker config, you should restart kafka in order to apply the changes on your server.properties file. In order to check it, just set a retention of a minute, and check the number of messages of the __consumer_offsets topic after some minutes (it should be empty), or, check wether your consumer restarts from the beginning (since there's no offset stored on the topic)